# GeoRss feeds in Drupal 7 not displayed

Tags: feeds, location

I have build a map in ArcGis online containing GeoRss feeds and I am trying to display it in my website. I used the webmap module but the GeoRss feeds are not displayed.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can do this? Not especially using this module, but rather also approaches on having this kind of map in my website.